# Faltings' height theorem for isogenies over finite fields

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, abelian-schemes, heights

For an Abelian scheme over a ring of integers in a number field, Faltings has a theorem that describes how the Faltings' height changes through an isogeny. There are multiple references for this statement and proof. See Proposition 4.1 in the notes *Faltings height* by Daniele Agostini ([pdf](https://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Ebakkerbe/faltings6.pdf)), for instance.

I am interested in the analogous statement over curves over a finite field, in particular when the isogeny has degree a power of $p$, the characteristic of the finite field.

Is any such statement true in this case and if so, what's a reference?

Comment: Quick note: the mathematician's name is "Gerd Faltings", so it should be "Faltings's" or "Faltings'", not "Falting's". The notes you link consistently make that mistake in the references.

Comment: And so did I! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I changed the link reference, because a blank 'this' sending the user to a pdf on  a personal webpage is not stable.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point! @davidroberts